# Blender exported animation not moving

Tags: three.js, blender

I have a blender file that a friend of mine exported.  I don't have experience with blender, but he exported a glTF and Published it and provided me the files.  I uploaded it to my host and the image shows, but the animation doesn't which he sees inside of blender.  Any thoughts?

https://shimmering-lolly-b8513c.netlify.app/

I ran it locally in a browser and the same thing.  I ran it on my host and just get the static image and no ability to rotate or anything.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have created your app with the "publication" feature of the [three.js editor](https://threejs.org/).

The resulting app does not automatically start animations so you need some additional code. However, you don't need a custom application for this. Instead, you can start animations in the `three.js` editor by adding a script to the glTF root node. E.g. the following code starts the first animation of the asset and makes sure it is updated in the animation loop.

```js
const animation = this.animations[ 0 ];
const mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( this );
const action = mixer.clipAction( animation );
action.play()

function update( event ) {

    mixer.update( event.delta / 1000 );

}
```